# ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCore'

Tags: swift, linker, macos-catalina, swift5

I am trying to manually link some swift code from the command-line. Here's what I'm doing:

```
ld \
  -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk \
  -lSystem \
  -arch x86_64 \
  -macosx_version_min 10.15 \
  -o ./bin/main \
  -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx \
  main.o
```

but that fails with the following output :

```
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCore'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreGraphics'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDarwin'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftIOKit'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftXPC'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDispatch'
```

If I use usr/lib/swift-5.0 instead of usr/lib/swift, the executable complains the dylibs are not usable with OS X more recent than 10.14.4.

What am I missing here? Can you help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This error can be fixed by adding **"swift file"** and **"Create Bridging Header"** in your Xcode.

Follow the below steps to resolve this.

- open Xcode project.
- Under your project select **new file**.
- Add swift file there.
- While adding swift file confirm **"Create Bridging Header"**.
- Clean your build
- Now make new build.